# QueryOver : Case Sensitive Like or Equals

Tags: nhibernate, iqueryable, queryover, icriteria

There are many posts online and on stack overflow talking about solving the issue of case insensitive likes.  I guess this is due to these peoples database being by default case sensitive.

Sql server by default uses a case insensitive collation, so i would never have that problem by default.

But unfortunately, I have the opposite problem.  I need to do a one off case sensitive equals or like.

I cannot set the collation of the table, so would ideally run some sql like this

```
WHERE Column COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'CaseSensitive'
```

As far as i can see, i dont understand why an InsensitiveLike has been implmeneted as surely we could have just done something like this

```
.Where(x=> x.Column.ToLower() == variable.ToLower())
```

But my issue is not able to be worked around in any other way that doing the above collaction change.

It would be nice if this was built in rather than having to write sql queries.

Have i missed something or is there really no way to do this?

Comment: I guess you could create a new dialect that derives from the default sql server dialect and register a new function that performs a case-sensitive like. Then you can register this as an extension to LINQ

Comment: Yeah i guess that too - but i was just wondering if i had missed something?

Comment: With criteria api you don't have to do that, see http://blog.schuager.com/2009/06/case-sensitive-queries-in-nhibernate.html

Comment: Yeah, just wanted QueryOver to get away from magic strings.